Securing Google Identification for iOS with Firebase AppCheck
I have a Flutter app targeting Android and iOS.
I am using Firebase Authentication and Firebase AppCheck.
This is working nicely in Android. I have turned on AppCheck enforcement for Authentication and only verified requests from my app are coming through, great!
I am now trying to configure this for iOS. This is what I have done:

Added iOS app to Firebase project
Added key to Apple Developer and linked it with AppCheck
Added debug token to Firebase Console
Ran flutterfire configure on my flutter project
Downloaded GoogleService-info.plist and added it to my project
Updated AppDelegate.swift as per below:

import UIKit
import Flutter

@UIApplicationMain
@objc class AppDelegate: FlutterAppDelegate {
  override func application(
    _ application: UIApplication,
    didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplication.LaunchOptionsKey: Any]?
  ) -> Bool {
    GeneratedPluginRegistrant.register(with: self)
    return super.application(application, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions: launchOptions)
  }
}

Everything works fine. I am able to log in with either email/password or Google. Nice!
I then noticed that in Firebase Console there is a new API that can be "enforced". So in addition to Authentication (Beta) there is "Google Identity for iOS". Being a security nerd I quickly clicked "enforce" for this.
I don't really understand why is this necessary. I thought that Authentication (Beta) already enforces any auth, including Google. This is what seems to happen on Android. Could not find any explanation online.
Anyway, to cut the long story short, after enforcing this, I cannot log in using Google any more. I am getting "Access Blocked: Authorization Error" and "Error 400: invalid_request". In Firebase Console attempts are logged as "Unverified: Outdated Client Requests".
For full disclosure I am using iPhone 16 Pro Xcode simulator on a Mac.
I am not sure what to do. I looked in Google Cloud Console everything looks OK. New iOS API key and service were created correctly AFAIK. Auto generated iOS API key is not using any app restrictions, and I have even removed API restrictions in an attempt to troubleshoot this, without any success. If anything else was wrong, like debug token, or firebase configuration, this would not work at all, i.e. email/password auth would be failing, or Google auth would not work with AppCheck enforcement turned off. But everything is working fine, except for "Google Identity for iOS".
Any help much appreciated.

You will need to cater for debug/simulator builds because these builds will not pass Apple's app attestation. Some information for native apps here - https://firebase.blog/posts/2024/02/app-check-comes-to-google-idp-ios/

Thanks, that's a very useful link! But it does not explain why it is not working for me. I am able to use AppCheck on my simulator with Firebase Auth and Firestore, so it can working in debug. The process is described here: https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/ios/appcheck/debug-provider. Only "Google Identity for iOS" does not work.

Have you checked that the flutterfire project supports this?

No I haven't. Do you know how to check?

You need to investigate their repo and see what version of the native libraries they are currently using
